# Unable to pass Adapter value to Activity

Tags: java, android

I am trying to pass MainAdapter.java string variable value to MainActivity.java

**MainAdapter.java** has a String value like:

```
static String strValue;

strValue = editText.getText().toString();
Log.d("strValue:", strValue); // it contains value
```

now i want *to put strValue to textResult* in **MainActivity.java**, like this:

```
textResult.setText(MainAdapter.strValue); //getting null pointer exception
```

so please let me know, **how to pass a simple string value from Adapter class to Activity class** ?

Comment: Post some code and your logcat....

Comment: try to define your adapter in MainActivity class and set textview in adpter directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public MyAdapter(){

}

public String getMyString(){
return "the string is:";
}
}
```

inside MyActivity you write

```
adapter.getMyString();
```

so it would be `textResult.setText(adapter.getMyString());`